# Serial commands not being flushed from Raspberry to Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, serial

I have an Arduino Mega controlling a matrix of 4x4 solenoids via the GPIOs opening/closing mosfet gates used as switches.

I'm trying to send commands via Serial from a Raspberry Pi 4 to the Arduino using the [WiringPi C++ library](http://wiringpi.com/reference/serial-library/), in order to control the solenoids.

Testing from the Arduino IDE, everything works fine: I read the command bytes from the Serial, and the solenoids respond quickly.

But when I run tests from the Raspberry, and use `screen` to follow the Serial output of the Arduino, I notice that most of the issued commands are skipped or delayed. I tried to flush the Serial at every loop I run on the Raspberry, hoping it would force the command to be sent, but nothing changes.

So my question is: *is Serial communication the best way to handle such commands between the two devices? Or is there another protocol I should consider for real-time control?*

Comment: Which type of serial?  I2C SPI UART 1-wire etc...

Comment: @Jasen I’m using a USB serial adapter between the RPi and the Arduino, and connecting through port `/dev/ttyACM0` if that helps.